# Is there a possible way to optimize this union all sql?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS total_amount,
       count(*) AS charge_count
FROM `chargetable`
WHERE appid='123'
  AND status='1'
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS total_amount,
       count(*) AS charge_count
FROM `chargetable`
WHERE appid='123'
  AND status='1'
  AND ch_created_time >='2015-07-28 00:00:00'
  AND ch_created_time <'2015-07-28 01:00:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS total_amount,
       count(*) AS charge_count
FROM `chargetable`
WHERE appid='123'
  AND status='1'
  AND ch_created_time >='2015-07-28 01:00:00'
  AND ch_created_time <'2015-07-28 02:00:00'
```

Maybe there's a MySQL function can do the time auto split 1 hour, I couldn't find it.

Comment: It's probably possible to rewrite it as a single query, but I don't quite understand your intent as in the end result there will be no way to tell the number apart as you don't include any source information. What is it you want to do?

Comment: I want to improve query performance, because there maybe houndreds of `union all`

Comment: Smacks forehead against wall

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an SQL fiddle) together with the desired result